# Program is returning 0 for values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

So I need to write a program to calculate the balance and minimum payment for a credit card statement. The program should use the event procedure shown below. The finance charge is 1.5% of the old balance. If the new balance is $20 or less, the minimum payment should be the entire new balance. Otherwise the minimum payment should be $20 plus 10% of the amount of the new balance above $20. The event procedure is:

```
Private Sub btnCalcBal_Paymt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcBal_Paymt.Click
    Dim oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment As Double
    InputData(oldBalance, charges, credits)
    CalculateNewValues(oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment)
    DisplayData(newBalance, minPayment)
End Sub

Sub InputData(oldBalance As Double, charges As Double, credits As Double)
    oldBalance = CDbl(txtOldBal.Text)
    charges = CDbl(txtCharges.Text)
    credits = CDbl(txtCredits.Text)
End Sub
Function CalculateNewValues(oldBalance As Double, newBalance As Double, minPayment As Double, charges As Double, credits As Double) As Double
    Dim rate As Double = 1.015
    newBalance = (rate * oldBalance) + charges - credits
    Return newBalance
    If newBalance <= 20 Then
        minPayment = newBalance
    Else
        Return minPayment + (0.1 * newBalance)
    End If
End Function

Sub DisplayData(newBalance As Double, minPayment As Double)
    txtNewBal.Text = newBalance.ToString("c")
    txtMinPmt.Text = minPayment.ToString("c")
End Sub
```

When I compile I get zero for the result. I can't figure out why.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Please expand on the topic, sir.

Comment: So I'm to write a program to calculate the balance and minimum payment for a credit card statement. The program should use the event procedure shown below. The finance charge is 1.5% of the old balance. If the new balance is $20 or less, the minimum payment should be the entire new balance. Otherwise the minimum payment should be $20 plus 10% of the amount of the new balance above $20. The event procedure is: Dim oldBalance, charge, credits, newBalance, minPayment as Double  InputData(oldBalance, charges, crdits) CalculateNewValues(oldBalance,charges,credits,newBal, minPmt)DispD(newBal,minPmt)

Comment: When I compile I get zero for the result. Can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. I'm a noob and been spending way more time on this problem than I should be.

Comment: I could knock this all down in like one function with minimal code. On another note the reason why your getting zero is because the scope of your variable are enclosed, not accessable after the block is ran. Put them outside and make them global or write one function to do it all.

Comment: Alzo in your calcnewvalues function your always returning newbalance without evaluating it, so in general this will fail your other checks

Comment: Do not make them global. Please do not make them global. There is no need for global variables in this instance. Either pass your properties around `byref` or consolidate your code into one function. Using global variables to accomplish what you want would cause three koalas and a panda to be sad for a week! And nobody wants that...

Comment: Thanks I made it byref Still working out the bugs.

Comment: Add Option Strict On to the top of your code file or turn it on in project properties.  Also, you have `Return newBalance` in the middle of your `CalculateNewValues` method.  As such, it will never reach the code after that.  You should be getting a warning about unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not modifying the variables correctly. The method with which you are passing the args to the subfunctions doesn't modify the values in your `btnCalcBal_Paymt_Click` method. You could use a `Function` to return the values you need, though the way your doing this it would be more difficult. Finally, you could use `ByRef` in your parameters so that the variables are passed to the subfunction by *reference*, not by *value* (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eek064h4.aspx)).

```
Private Sub btnCalcBal_Paymt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcBal_Paymt.Click
    Dim oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment As Double
    InputData(oldBalance, charges, credits)
    CalculateNewValues(oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment)
    DisplayData(newBalance, minPayment)
End Sub

Sub InputData(ByRef oldBalance As Double, ByRef charges As Double, ByRef credits As Double)
    oldBalance = CDbl(txtOldBal.Text)
    charges = CDbl(txtCharges.Text)
    credits = CDbl(txtCredits.Text)
End Sub
...
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I didn't down vote you but your code uses `dim` outside of a function which, from what limited info we have, could make them global variables, which is bad. At the very least they are class wide variables which are declared(and are assigned memory slots) regardless of whether or not they are actually used. The original questioner would be better served marking all of his parameters as `byref` and then modifying the values.

Answer (score 0):

You are using way too many functions to accomplish a fairly simple task. You can do everything you want inside a single event handler. Like:

```
Private Sub btnCalcBal_Paymt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcBal_Paymt.Click
    Dim oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment As Double
    oldBalance = CDbl(txtOldBal.Text)
    charges = CDbl(txtCharges.Text)
    credits = CDbl(txtCredits.Text)

    Dim rate As Double = 1.015
    newBalance = (rate * oldBalance) + charges - credits
    If newBalance <= 20 Then
        minPayment = newBalance
    Else
        minPayment = minPayment + (0.1 * newBalance)
    End If

    txtNewBal.Text = newBalance.ToString("c")
    txtMinPmt.Text = minPayment.ToString("c")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's too late, but perhaps other struggling students can use this. This works and it does what the book wants you to do.

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click


    Dim oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment As Double
    InputData(oldBalance, charges, credits)
    CalculateNewValues(oldBalance, charges, credits, newBalance, minPayment)
    DisplayData(newBalance, minPayment)


End Sub

Sub InputData(ByRef oldBalance As String, ByRef charges As String, ByRef credits As String)
    oldBalance = CDbl(txtOldBal.Text)
    charges = CDbl(txtCharges.Text)
    credits = CDbl(txtCredits.Text)
End Sub

Sub CalculateNewValues(ByRef oldBalance As Double, ByRef charges As Double, ByRef credits As Double, ByRef newBalance As Double, ByRef minPayment As Double)
    Dim rate As Double = 1.015
    newBalance = (rate * oldBalance) + charges - credits
    If newBalance <= 20 Then
        minPayment = newBalance
    Else
        minPayment = ((newBalance - 20) * 0.1) + 20
    End If

End Sub

Sub DisplayData(newBalance As Double, minPayment As Double)
    lblMinPay.Text = minPayment.ToString("C")
    lblNewBal.Text = newBalance.ToString("C")
End Sub

End Class
```